# IP67 enclosure which provides solar power

Tags: solar-power

I program small, devices like ESP32 and occasionally Raspberry Pi Zero W2. The Pi is the larger, at Length: 65mm, Width: 30mm, Height: 5mm.

I am seeking a "weatherproof" box, so let's say IP67, to me use them outdoors. I don't want to constantly change batteries, so would like the box to provide solar power, to keep the batteries charged. Perhaps a solar cell as a lid, perhaps something that stands beside the box and connects to provide power.

I may also wish to hang sensors from the box, so there would need to be opening for that.